# When and where to clear input stream in c++

Tags: c++, io

Here is an example from **accelerated c++** :

```
// read homework grades from an input stream into a `vector<double>'
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in) {
       // get rid of previous contents
       hw.clear();

       // read homework grades
       double x;
       while (in >> x)
          hw.push_back(x);

       // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
       in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}
```

The `in.clear()` line is supposed to clear possible errors produced by previous inputs, but why is it not cleared before we start to input, i.e. before the `while (in >> x)` line? In fact, wouldn't it be safer to clear the input stream twice (before and after inputting to hw)?

Comment: Pay attention to what it's being called on. They do different things to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the flags after you've reached the end of the stream because you intend to reach the end of the stream. A flag raised by another function may not have been intended and may need handling.